# Selenium Python I am trying to write a value into a column in a HTML table using send_keys

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a HTML table with some rows and a column on a web page.  I am trying to write a value into the column for each row.

Row 1 has the value STR[wi si 90] LC2[wi si 90]

Rows 2 has the value STR[wi si 90] LC3[wi si 90]

Row 3 has the value STR[wi si 90] PCD[maj mpc]

For each row I would like to replace the value 90 with 98
E.g. Row 1 should now be STR[wi si 98] LC2[wi si 98]

I have tried the following code but it is not doing anything:

```
def enter_a_street_rule_from_street_rules_listbox(self, street_rule, new_street_rule): # enter the street rule value so all the street rules have the value 98 from page 13 of the regression test script e.g. STR[wi si 98] LC2[wi si 98]
    # Params street_rule : E.g. STR[wi si 90] LC2[wi si 90]
    # Params new_street_rule : E.g. STR[wi si 98] LC2[wi si 98]
    street_rules_listbox_element =  self.get_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="data_configuration_add_data_object_tab_address_rules_tb_level_rules_street"]//tr//td//div[contains(text(),"%s")]' % street_rule)
    street_rules_listbox_element.send_keys(new_street_rule)
```

The code to call the method is:

```
data_objects_address_rules_tab.enter_a_street_rule_from_street_rules_listbox("STR[wi si 90] LC2[wi si 90]", "STR[wi si 98] LC2[wi si 98]")
```

HTML snippet:

```
    <table id="data_configuration_add_data_object_tab_address_rules_tb_level_rules_street" class="GFNQNVHJE border" cellspacing="0" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus="true" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingblur="true" style="min-width: 350px;">
    <thead aria-hidden="false">
        <colgroup>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="GFNQNVHCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
                    <td class="GFNQNVHBD GFNQNVHDD GFNQNVHED">
                        <td class="GFNQNVHBD GFNQNVHDD GFNQNVHOD">
                            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-7176" style="outline-style:none;">STR[wi si 90] LC2[wi si 90]</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="GFNQNVHCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
                        <tr class="GFNQNVHCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="2">
                            <td class="GFNQNVHBD GFNQNVHDD GFNQNVHED">
                                <td class="GFNQNVHBD GFNQNVHDD GFNQNVHOD">
                                    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-7176" style="outline-style:none;">STR[wi si 90] PCD[maj mpc]</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tbody style="display: none;">
                            <tfoot style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true"/>
</table>
```

I can use the following XPATH to identify the element:

```
By.XPATH, '//table[@id="data_configuration_add_data_object_tab_address_rules_tb_level_rules_street"]//tr//td//div[contains(text(),"%s")]' % street_rule
```

How do i replace the value 90 with 98 for each row?
Thanks, Riaz

I have got it work now.  I found an alternative way which was to click the add button on the GUI.   I noticed an Input tag appears in the HTML.  I located the input element and then used send_keys to enter the value into the input field.

The code to locate the Input tag and enter the value is:

```
def enter_a_street_rule_in_street_rules_listbox(self, new_street_rule):
    # Params new_street_rule : E.g. STR[wi si 98] LC2[wi si 98]
    street_rules_listbox_element = self.get_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="data_configuration_add_data_object_tab_address_rules_tb_level_rules_street"]//tr//td//div//input[@value="Enter rule"]')
    street_rules_listbox_element.send_keys(new_street_rule)
```

The XPATH to locate the element is:

```
'//table[@id="data_configuration_add_data_object_tab_address_rules_tb_level_rules_street"]//tr//td//div//input[@value="Enter rule"]'
```

The calling code, to call the method:

```
data_objects_address_rules_tab.click_add_button()
data_objects_address_rules_tab.enter_a_street_rule_in_street_rules_listbox("STR[wi si 98] LC2[wi si 98]")
```

Comment: sendkeys only works with input tags like textbox, textarea. You need to use javascript to change the html in the div with innerhtml function..

Comment: Thanks, I have found an alternative way to do it.  I can click the add button on the GUi and an Input tag appears in the HTML table.  I used send_keys to enter the value into the input field.  I will put my code at the bottom of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.send_keys()` only works for elements that take keyboard input. I don't think this is the case here. You are talking about changing the HTML of the page. This can be done but it's only temporary. Once the page (or that section of the page) is reloaded, the changes will be lost.

If you still want to do this, you can use `JavascriptExecutor` and set `.innerHTML` to `"STR[wi si 98] LC2[wi si 98]"` or whatever you want.

Comment: If i enter the values in the html table on the webpage I can click the save button to save the changes.  There is a save button on the page

Comment: An alternative I can do is I can select all the checkboxes from the html table on the page and delete the street rules.  I can then click the add button and add the new street rule.  An input field appears in the HTML table when i click the add button

Comment: If that's true, you shouldn't need to set the `.innerHTML` on the page. You should script the way the user would update the table on the page. I can't tell you what that is since I haven't seen it.